# What’s the equivalent for Oracle’s SQL PARTITION BY keyword in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

I have the following table:

| id | grade | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 50 |
| A | 3 | 55 |
| A | 2 | 65 |
| A | 4 | 60 |
| B | 4 | 40 |
| B | 1 | 55 |
| B | 2 | 50 |
| B | 3 | 45 |
| C | 1 | 70 |
| C | 2 | 80 |
| C | 4 | 90 |
| C | 3 | 100 |

- “grade“ ranges from 1 (lowest) to 4 (highest).

Here’s what I want to do:

For each id, return the sum of each grade’s score and the score of the next higher grade.

Answer (score 0):

In DolphinDB, you can use the following SQL keywords/built-in functions for windowing calculations within groups:

1. `context by` - divide the records into groups
2. `csort` - sort the records in each group
3. 1. the moving window functions (e.g., `msum`, `mmin`, `mrank`) - for moving
      window calculation within each group

The following script could answer your question:

```
//1. generate the table in your question 
id = take(`A`B`C, 12).sort()
gap=[1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3]
score = [50, 55, 65, 60, 40, 55, 50, 45, 70, 80, 90, 100]
exam_result = table(id, gap, score)

//2. within each id group, for each gap, sum its score and the score of the next higher gap
select id, gap, msum(score, 2, 1) as total
from exam_result
context by id 
csort gap desc
```

The result:

| id | grade | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 60 |
| A | 3 | 115 |
| A | 2 | 120 |
| A | 1 | 115 |
| B | 4 | 40 |
| B | 3 | 85 |
| B | 2 | 95 |
| B | 1 | 105 |
| C | 4 | 90 |
| C | 3 | 190 |
| C | 2 | 180 |
| C | 1 | 150 |